# Providing "Art of debugging code" documentation via StackDoc

Tags: discussion, debugging-questions, documentation

I would like to know if Documentation<sup>TM</sup> will include the possibility to write some sort of reference documentation on how to debug applications in a specific language.

At the moment, I see a good amount of questions that could easily be solved by the OP himself if only he knew how to run his code via a debugger or if he used basic debugging techniques. I am mainly talking about Java questions, but I'm quite sure this problem is also present in most language tags.

These questions and their corresponding answers add no value to Stack Overflow. Even worse, answering them doesn't really help the OP. True, they do end up fixing the code problem they are facing, which is a trivial coding mistake most of the time, but in the long run they never really learn *how* to fix such kind of problem, and to me this is a real problem. I believe we would greatly increase the help value of SO if we could help those users to become better developers by giving them tools to become better, and not only quick fixes to small coding mistakes.

[This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285823/) asked earlier this year tried to reach a consensus, with the objective of writing a canonical question on the art of debugging C++ code. I believe a question wouldn't be the correct tool, once we have Documentation<sup>TM</sup>, provided that it would support such a thing.

Comment: Many posters do not debug in any language, maybe because they don't know how, (in which case they cannot develop software and should stop trying), or cannot be bothered, (so why should we bother).   According to posts, some seem to write their software, get it to compile/link, run it and, when it does not immediately do what they want and expect, sit around and stare at the source for two weeks, then post it here.   I don't see how any more help would err.. help.

Comment: @MartinJames I agree, there are many users like that. However, if this "art of debugging" thing helps 5-6% of them, then we have helped some to become better developers. Which in the end is linked to the main goal of SO.

Comment: @MartinJames While those users do exist, there is also a great volume of users on this site that are new to whatever language, or programming in general, and could benefit greatly from streamlined information on how to debug the most common problems that occur in that language. Sure we all know great debugging techniques to the point where they are muscle memory, but for someone new they may not even know where to look to find debugging techniques, and the answers to their questions are not going to help anyone else learn how to debug their problems.

Comment: That said, being that Documentation™ isn't even a thing yet, this post may be jumping the gun a bit. Until we get an idea of what the feature is really going to be, or if it is even going to survive the beta, I don't think this question is objectively answerable. Unless of course the question is asking will this kind of thing be allowed, in which case it could be answerable but may be better asked on the [followup to the original announcement](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered).

Comment: Something like Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) could be useful, but I think @TinyGiant is right, this may be jumping the gun somewhat.

Comment: In the meantime, you can point them to the [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help topic. At the very bottom there is a list of links, one of which is How to debug small programs. It's a pretty good basic, generic (not specific to any language) guide.

Comment: @JeffC - Forgot that article was linked there. We could also send people to [bathe their code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281270/what-does-rubber-duck-mean-in-debug-help) :)

Comment: This is an interesting concept, but not sure if it would really help.  For whatever reasons, a lot of folks need to overcome some psychological hurdle(s) just to start using debuggers/profilers.  If they could only learn to make friends with these lovely dev tools.

Comment: @ChrisO Maybe it would not help every beginner. But if we can help some of them, then we'll end up helping more developers becoming better. I can surely see how big of a task debugging an application can be if you don't have a clue how to do it. Anyhow, with this question I was more interested in hearing from StackDoc people if they only built this tool for code documentation, or for larger purposes, such as how to debug an application. I believe this could be as useful as code documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to say yes, based on [this quote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/901641):

> Here’s what we’re thinking goes into Documentation:
>
> [...]
>
> - Short (single page) tutorial-like material
>
>   - Things like “Getting Started,” “Making HTTP Queries,” etc.

This quote seems to suggest to me that they think that a short tutorial on how to debug in a specific language or framework would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the problem raised by the OP entirely--I see exactly the same thing in JavaScript. However, there are already lots of guides to debugging out there, which people obviously don't visit. Why would they visit the one in StackDoc?

I suggest a change to the wording of the "debugging help" off-topic reason as follows:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error, the shortest code (**properly formatted**) necessary to reproduce it in the question itself, **and a description of how you have attempted to debug the problem and the results**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.