# Is there any language-specific effort to better help new contributors asking questions?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

We frequently ask new contributors to improve their questions to comply with [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25677689/how-to-use-where-clause-using-ssp-class-php-datatables) and [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Those pages provide some basic advice and show what a good question **should** look like.

However, many, if not most, of the new contributors coming to ask questions are absolute beginners and do not know *how to gather the required information* to form a good question since they have no clue about using debuggers, finding error logs, or even enabling error logging at all.

This is different in each language and cannot be advised generally, e.g. in **PHP** questions I often see people providing either no dump at all or, if they do, it is a `print_r` not showing any relevant types. `var_dump` is more verbose, however, when this is used to create reproducible examples, you would have to recode array/object structures by hand (typically entire database result tables). In my experience, many people have not heard about `var_export` generating executable source.

Both help pages above are a nice summary to give a first idea of how questions should be asked. I would like to see a more language-specific automated help system when asking questions. It should recognize or just ask which coding language the question belongs to and teach the asker how to gather the needed information, i.e. error logs, dumps in a proper format, etc.

Is there already something similar I did not see, or is it planned?

Comment: I am not a native speaker. Please feel free to improve my English expression.

Comment: Could be helpful if it gets read, but I'm not all that optimistic of how much of an impact it would have - after all, as you say, `We frequently ask new contributers to improve their question to comply with How to ask and Minimal, complete, verifiable example.`. The many who don't look at the *basics* of how to ask an answerable question before posting probably wouldn't get much out of language-specific MCVE tutorial pages.

Comment: Sometimes, tag wikis contain the sort of MCVE-creation guidelines you're describing. If a tag wiki doesn't contain anything about it yet, you could create it, and then link users to that page.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Do you mean short links like `[ask]` / `[mcve]`? How can I create a new 'tag wiki'? Can you provide a deep link?

Comment: For example, for PHP, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info See the `I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?` section, feel free to expand it if you want

Comment: @CertainPerformance As I understood so far, those tags are meant to tag a question helping answering contributors to filter them, aren't they? Or can I create tags not available to questions as well? Do I have the possibility to create a new short link like `[mcve]`, e.g. `[ask-php]`?

Comment: No, `[MCVE], [ask], [tour]` (maybe more) are special and separate, only changeable by the mods.

Comment: The best help in their asking questions would *keep them* from asking questions. If people knew how to use a debugger, for example, only a small fraction of questions would ever roll in. Then again I used to beat that `var_export` drum too and eventually gave up on it. Some things refuse to catch on.

Comment: @PaulCrovella It might sound weird, however, "keeping them from asking question" would be ideal for the platform. SO should be a place where really good questions are asked to solve specific tasks, i.e. it should be more like a knowledge database. It has become a debugging platform with only a few generic questions applicable to similar cases. Most common issues have hundreds of duplicates.

Comment: Related: [Can we support users who do not understand how to debug their code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364282) [OP doesn't know how to debug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313045) Slightly more related: [Proposal for canonical question "how do I use a debugger to debug my C++ code?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285823)

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of language-specific efforts to help people asking questions, however, they're not very well organized.

First, there's the tag wiki for every tag that might contain tips for asking questions on that tag.

Then, there are Q+A's on meta for asking questions on specific languages, such as [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/)

There are also similar efforts on Stack Overflow, such as [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). However, as you can see, that might not be on-topic.

There are also off-site efforts which I'm not going to link here.

Generally, other efforts can be found under the tag wiki, which should be the place to start when seeking help asking a question under a specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to see a more language-specific automated help system when asking questions. It should recognize or just ask which coding language the question belongs to and teach the asker how to gather the needed information, i.e. error logs, dumps in a proper format, etc.

In my not-so-humble opinion, if you don't have the knowledge to provide an MCVE, **you should not be asking a question on Stack Overflow**, period - you should be spending some time reading tutorials about the absolute fundamentals of the language. Because at that point, you know so little that you probably don't even know the right thing to ask, so even if you could provide a valid MCVE, your question is likely to be low quality anyway.

As such, this suggestion in trying to help askers even further is likely to have no measurable effect on the number of bad questions posted - because now those questions won't get closed for being too broad or unclear, but instead as duplicates or typos.

tl;dr you're suggesting a lot of extra effort for something that's unlikely to change the outcome.