# Do we have any statistics on the number of questions that are abandoned during writing?

Tags: support, statistics

I often find myself starting to write a question on SO, and then finding that in writing up the question it helps me to figure out the answer - so I abandon the SO question before clicking "Ask".

Do we have any statistics on that?

Comment: AKA the rubber duck ratio.

Comment: What would be the benefits of having these stats?

Comment: @Paradox, Depending on what information is available, it could show how often the "Have you checked these questions" suggestions are helpful.

Comment: FWIW, this has happened to me a few times but frequently I post the question anyway.  And then I [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) because if I had a hard time finding the solution, maybe somebody else did too...

Comment: @Andy having metrics on how many people clicked "ask question," then clicked one of the suggestions, then abandoned the page would be very helpful.

Comment: @BradLarson "Rubber duck" Does it mean that explaining your problem, even to a rubber duck, makes you figure out the solution? In my environment we call that "teddybearing", as having a teddy bear on the table looks less creepy than a rubber duck ;-)

Comment: @LeifNeland Keep a Jon Skeet doll. That's the best :)

Comment: On the other hand, asking a co-worker: "Can you be my teddy bear?" is also a little creepy...

Comment: @Andy: I personally find the "Have you checked these questions" more efficient than the search tool.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Agreed. It's probable the only "Have you checked" titled feature that is actually useful, on any website ever.

Comment: I guess whether it's the "Rubber Duck" ratio or the "Teddy Bear" ratio depends on whether it's [not an awk question](http://lists.ethernal.org/oldarchives/cantlug-0211/msg00174.html).

Comment: @LeifNeland http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281270/what-does-rubber-duck-mean-in-debug-help

Comment: @TomášZato Windows should take advantage of this: "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..." should mean "Windows is starting to post SO question about the problem and will check the recommendations there..." (instead of spinning indefinitely and accomplishing absolutely nothing ever)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***We shouldn't.***

If we had, one thing would be for sure; they would be heavily based on speculation(s), making them unreliable.

I am telling that via my own experience. There are many times I have started writing a questions and then before/after finishing it, ending up deleting it instead of posting it. Some reasons that come in mind:

1. Found the answer while writing (thus reading the question).
2. Realized that my question is awful (either unclear or incomplete),
   thus aborted posting.
3. My question was just too broad for SO.
4. I lost internet connection. In the meantime stuff happened and when
   I came back and SO/browser remembered my question I didn't want to
   post it after all (because in the meantime the need for this
   disappeared).
5. Rechecking the auto-suggested questions and actually find the answer
   there (well even if we marked that the OP clicked on a suggested
   question), then if he aborts posting, what does it mean? That the
   other question solved his problem or that in the meanwhile he
   figured it out? Been there, done both.
6. I have aborted posting, because I am late on my date, so having me
   to select a reason for the abortion will probably have me killed by
   the woman.

..and probably I am forgetting something...Anyway, I only came back to my cube to write that, cutting me time off my tea break, hope you find the answer worthy. ;)

---

<sub>I have never used a rubber duck (or an alive one) and probably won't, thus starting writing a question seems much more promising! :)</sub>

Comment: 1-3 and 5 at least are also reasons I've cut off writing an answer myself. As a follow-up, then - what do you think of asking anyone who cancels to (optionally) click a quick radio-button explaining why? I mean I know these things are never perfect, but I agree with the comments above that it would be useful to have some kind of knowledge of how useful the suggested answers are; and also "Rubber-ducking" is another way that SO helps people without them even asking a question!

Comment: @simonalexander2005 ehhm, personally I wouldn't like to have to click the reason, so it should be optionally for sure! I mean most times I have found myself aborting posting is because I want/must/have to leave the site/computer ASAP. But if it would be optional, then it would be OK, I guess..See my edit.